# Time Machine device with hostname changed: how to fix it?

Tags: network, backup, time-machine

I have setup a Raspberry Pi to be my Time Machine remote device. It seems to work properly since I have been able to do some backups.

In the meantime I have changed the Raspberry Pi hostname and so Time Machine is not able to find anymore the device in the network (since it is still looking for the old hostname).

In order to fix this issue I have tried to change the Time Machine setting file (`/Library/Preferences/com.apple.TimeMachine.plist`), by replacing the old hostname with the new one in its raw content. However, after a reboot, the file in question is replaced with a new blank file and Time Machine results to be not configured.

Is it possible to tell Time Machine to find for another device in local network? If yes, how?

Comment: Can‘t you just connect TM to the new device/name in System Preferences?

Comment: Please post this as an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The issue can be resolved by removing the old device from Time Machine settings and adding the new one.

After connecting to the new device (in this case, the same Raspberry Pi but with a different hostname), if Time Machine detects the presence of some previous backups, user will be prompted to start new backups from scratch or to continue from the already made ones.

Without removing the old device, Time Machine will actually only ask whether alternate the devices in the backup execution.